# What is the difference between '&&' and '&' in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Recently, I observed a very interesting result in Ruby while making use of && and & for the input combination of 0 & 1.

Can someone please explain the below output with respect to the above mentioned two operators? The below is implemented using Ruby 2.0.0-p451

```
2.0.0-p451 :006 > 0 && 1
 => 1 


2.0.0-p451 :008 > 0 & 1
 => 0
```

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`&&` is a *boolean* `and`. It returns the second argument if the first argument is true-ish. Because `0` is true-ish in Ruby, `1` is returned.

`&` is a *bitwise* `and`. It compares the bit representation of the values. Because (imaging 8 bit) `00000000` (`0`) and `00000001` (`1`) have no `1` digits in common, `00000000` (`0`) is returned.

Comment: Your answer is more precise wrt my question. Thanks. Also, this kinda reminds me that why the below code works(prints "hi") in Ruby. `p "hi" if 0 `.

Answer (score 12):

`&&` is the logical AND operator. It will be truthy, IFF both operands are truthy. And it is lazy (aka short-circuiting), which means it will stop evaluating as soon as the result has been fully determined. (So, since both operands need to be truthy, if the first operand is falsy, you already know that the result is going to be falsy, without even evaluating the second operand.) It will also not just return `true` or `false`, but rather return the operand which determines the outcome. IOW: if `a` is falsy, it'll return `a`, otherwise it'll return `b`:

```
nil && (loop {})
# => nil
# Note: the infinite loop is *not* evaluated
# Note: the return value is nil, not false

true && nil
# => nil

true && 'Hello'
# => 'Hello'
```

`&` simply calls the method `&`. It will do whatever the object wants it to do:

```
def (weirdo = Object.new).&(other)
  puts 'Whoah, weird!'
  'Hello, ' + other
end

weirdo & 'World'
# Whoah, weird!
# => 'Hello, World'
```

In general, `&` and its brother `|` are expected to perform conjunction and disjunction. So, for booleans, they are perform AND and OR ([`TrueClass#&`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/TrueClass.html#method-i-26), [`FalseClass#&`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/FalseClass.html#method-i-26), [`NilClass#&`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/NilClass.html#method-i-26), [`TrueClass#|`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/TrueClass.html#method-i-7C), [`FalseClass#|`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/FalseClass.html#method-i-7C), [`NilClass#|`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/NilClass.html#method-i-7C)) with the exception that `&` and `|` are standard method calls and thus always evaluate their argument and that they always return `true` or `false` and not their arguments.

For [`Set`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/)s, they perform set intersection and set union: [`Set#&`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-26), [`Set#|`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-7C). For other collections (specifically `Array`s), they also perform set operations: [`Array#&`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-26), [`Array#|`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-7C).

For [`Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Integer.html)s, they perform BITWISE-AND of the two-complement's binary representation: [`Fixnum#&`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Fixnum.html#method-i-26), [`Bignum#&`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Bignum.html#method-i-26), [`Fixnum#|`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Fixnum.html#method-i-7C), [`Bignum#|`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Bignum.html#method-i-7C).

Comment: Wonderful insights, thank you very much for the extra notes. +1 from me is just the least I can do to attribute the time you've taken to write these down. I also kinda feel that the && operator is also smart as it knows when to cut off in terms of its operands :).

Answer (score 0):

One is a boolean operator, the other is a bitwise operator:

```
  # Bitwise operators
  a = 78      #  01001110
  b = 54      #  00110110
  puts (a&b)  #  00000110 = 6
  puts (a|b)  #  01111110 = 126
  puts (a^b)  #  01111000 = 120
  puts (~a)   #  10110001 = -79
  puts (a<<2) #  00111000 = 312
  puts (a>>2) #  00010011 = 19
```

http://www.public.traineronrails.com/courses/ruby/pages/008-rubyoperators.html

Comment: Bitwise when working with Fixnums, `&` and `|` are logical operators when working with `true` and `false`. And they're set-wise operators when working with Array and Set instances.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm) gives a good explanation of the different operators in Ruby.

`&&` is logical AND operator in ruby.

```
> a = true
> b = true
> c = false
> a && b
 => true 
> a && c
 => false
```

`&` is the [bitwise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) AND operator in ruby. Per the wikipedia article on the description for the "bitwise AND operator":

> A bitwise AND takes two binary representations of equal length and
>   performs the logical AND operation on each pair of corresponding bits.
>   The result in each position is 1 if the first bit is 1 and the second
>   bit is 1; otherwise, the result is 0.

Answer (score 0):

`&&` is logical and. Which is to say, `a && b` returns true if a is true and b is true. `&` is bitwise and. In (almost) any other language, logical and of 0 and 1 would be 0, because (almost) all other languages consider 0 to be false. But in ruby, anything except `nil` and `false` are considered to be truthy.

Answer (score 0):

***&&*** is a Logical operator which will always return a boolean value.
z
 It's either **true** if both of the values are true

```
true && true
```

and will return **false** if any of the value is false

```
false && true
```

Now comes to second point **&** Operator.
Here are two answer for the **&** Operator.

```
& is a Bitwise operator as mentioned in above answers, It compares bit representation in the form of 0 and 1.
```

---

Another Important answer is, In upgradation of Ruby 2.6 its implementation is somewhat modified.

> [**&** is represented as intersection operator](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/12/ruby-2-7-new-features/#Arrayintersection)

For ex:

```
[1, 2, 3] & [2, 3, 4]
$ [2, 3]
```